# devtools::test() in parallel?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, devtools, testthat

I have a test suite using `testthat` containing several files in `R/tests` and I would like to test them in parallel to speed up testing. Are there any implemented methods in `devtools`, `testthat`, or elsewhere towards this end?

I tried doing it "manually" using the `future` packages, but the text rendering of `stdout` is unreadable:

```r
# Get a vector of test files without "test-" and ".R"
test_files = list.files("tests/testthat", "test-")
test_filters = stringr::str_replace_all(test_files, c("test-|\\.R"), "")

# Run test for each file in parallel
future::plan(future::multiprocess)
future.apply::future_mapply(devtools::test, filter = test_filters)
```

Comment: If you are open to alternate frameworks, `tinytest` has parallel test runners baked in. A number of folks are using it happily, myself included, as well as some folks who came from `testthat`.  I could expand, but maybe you want to stay with `testthat` ...

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel, `tinytest` looks very promising and I may want to transition (for other reasons as well). So I'd appreciate a `tinytest` answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new `testthat >= 3.0` introduces parallel tests. You just need to add to your description

```
Config/testthat/parallel: true
Config/testthat/edition: 3
```

and `devtools::test()` should work in parallel.

See the [parallel vignette](https://testthat.r-lib.org/articles/parallel.html). for more information

Comment: What if you don't have a DESCRIPTION file in your project?

Answer (score 2):

With the caveat of a long-time user of `RUnit` who more recently switched to `tinytest`, the feature you are looking for exists in `tinytest` already. I would think that someone has or may build a parallel test runner for `testthat` at some point, but in the 'here and now' we do have `tinytest` with very fine behavior, good documentation and leads for converting from `RUnit` or `testthat`.

My favourite features of `tinytest` are the default installation of tests in the package, the lack of other dependencies and the parallel runner.

And another caveat coming: I like the command-line for this *way more* than an R prompt because there may always be some side-effects of some form.  So I added a little test runner wrappre [tt.r](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/littler/blob/master/inst/examples/tt.r) to [littler](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/littler):

```
edd@rob:~$ tt.r -h
Usage: tt.r [-h] [-x] [-a] [-b] [-d] [-f] [-n NCPUS] [-p] [-s] [-z] [ARG...]

-a --all            use test_all mode [default: FALSE]
-b --build          use build-install-test mode [default: FALSE]
-d --directory      use directory mode [default: FALSE]
-f --file           use file mode [default: FALSE]
-n --ncpus NCPUS    use 'ncpus' in parallel [default: getOption]
-p --package        use package mode [default: FALSE]
-s --silent         use silent and do not print result [default: FALSE]
-z --effects        suppress side effects [default: FALSE]
-h --help           show this help text
-x --usage          show help and short example usage 
edd@rob:~$
```

(I should add here that writing such wrapper is easy thanks to `docopt`.)

And then we simply do

```
edd@rob:~$ tt.r -n 4 -p anytime
starting worker pid=642068 on localhost:11092 at 17:11:25.636
starting worker pid=642067 on localhost:11092 at 17:11:25.654
starting worker pid=642065 on localhost:11092 at 17:11:25.687
starting worker pid=642066 on localhost:11092 at 17:11:25.689
Running test_gh_issue_12.R............    2 tests OK 
Running test_gh_issue_56.R............    7 tests OK 
Running test_gh_issue_33.R............    2 tests OK 

Running test_all_formats.R............    0 tests    ris or Windows or Release
Running test_assertions.R.............    2 tests OK 
Running test_calc_unique.R............    4 tests OK 
Running test_gh_issue_100.R...........    2 tests OK 
Running test_simple.R.................   34 tests OK 
Running test_utilities.R..............    2 tests OK 
Running test_bulk.R................... 2328 tests OK 
[1] "All ok, 2383 results"
edd@rob:~$
```

You see a little bit of output got swallowed there.

You can of course also run this by hand from R:

```
R> tinytest::test_package("anytime", ncpu=4)
starting worker pid=651865 on localhost:11762 at 17:14:45.970
starting worker pid=651864 on localhost:11762 at 17:14:45.980
starting worker pid=651863 on localhost:11762 at 17:14:45.980
starting worker pid=651862 on localhost:11762 at 17:14:45.984
Running test_gh_issue_12.R............    2 tests
 Exited 'test_all_formats.R' at line 24. Skipping Solaris or Windows or ReleaseOK 
Running test_all_formats.R............    0 tests    
Running test_gh_issue_56.R............    7 tests OK 
Running test_assertions.R.............    2 tests OK 
Running test_gh_issue_33.R............    2 tests OK 
Running test_calc_unique.R............    4 tests OK 
Running test_gh_issue_100.R...........    2 tests OK 
Running test_simple.R.................   34 tests OK 
Running test_utilities.R..............    2 tests OK 
Running test_bulk.R................... 2328 tests OK 
[1] "All ok, 2383 results"
R>
```

There are other runners for *file*, *directory*, a build+install+test cycle and more.  And hey if after all of this you still don't like it Mark will give you your money back :)

PS Here and eg in `Rcpp` I have some tests "dimmed" because they produce an ungodly amount of cmdline noise so that only happens in package tests when the opt-in var is set.  Hence the few 'zero tests run' above. That is my setup and not a `tinytest` issue.